# OneDrive Pause Sync for Disconnected Users

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, onedrive

We have shared machine where multiple users login and just lock their screen later. We want onedrive sync to pause for all such users who are not in active state on that machine. I am able to get the list of users programmatically in a text file who are not in active state like user1, user2...in separate lines in a text file.
**I need a script where we can take the above user list as input and pause the onedrive sync for these users. Could you please help me with a script which takes usernames as input and pauses onedrive sync for them?**

I tried to get the list of all disconnected users and was able to get their names programmatically but unable to find any powershell command to pause sync for specific user

Comment: NOTE: We understand if we log off these users the sync will stop but we cannot log off these users as per business requirement

Comment: you could use a scheduled task with a trigger on connect and disconnect session to resume/suspend the onedrive process. Not perfect but should work

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct way to pause OneDrive sync for disconnected users remotely.

As a workaround, you can try to use Group Policy to prevent the sync app from generating network traffic until users sign in.

About using OneDrive policies to control sync settings, you can refer to the official article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/use-group-policy

Comment: But in this option user needs to sign in to onedrive. Is there an option to sign him automatically

Comment: Yes, if the options is enabled, user needs to sign in OneDrive manually. Per my knowlege, there is no better way to pause OneDrive sync for disconnected users.